# Errors associated with a creating a template class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, queue, priority-queue

I am creating a PriorityQueue template class that houses an inner friend Node class. When I attempt to compile the below code, I am now receiving these errors:

```
    PriorityQueue.h:20:12: error: declaration of ‘class T’
   template<typename T> class Node
            ^
PriorityQueue.h:16:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class T’
 template <typename T> class PriorityQueue
           ^
PriorityQueue.h:22:25: error: expected nested-name-specifier
        friend typename PriorityQueue<T>;
                        ^
PriorityQueue.h:22:41: error: invalid declarator before ‘;’ token
        friend typename PriorityQueue<T>;
                                        ^
PriorityQueue.cpp:66:1: error: ‘PriorityQueue<T>::Node’ is not a type
 PriorityQueue<T>::Node::Node()
 ^
PriorityQueue.cpp:66:30: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Node’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 PriorityQueue<T>::Node::Node()
                              ^
PriorityQueue.cpp:66:30: error: invalid use of dependent type ‘typename PriorityQueue<T>::Node’

PriorityQueue.cpp:74:1: error: ‘PriorityQueue<T>::Node’ is not a type
 PriorityQueue<T>::Node::Node(T data, int *index, float priority)
 ^
```

PriorityQueue.cpp:74:64: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Node’ with no type [-fpermissive]
    PriorityQueue::Node::Node(T data, int *index, float priority)
                                                                   ^
    PriorityQueue.cpp:74:64: error: invalid use of dependent type ‘typename PriorityQueue::Node’

PriorityQueue.h:

```
#ifndef PRIORITYQUEUE_H_
#define PRIORITYQUEUE_H_
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> class Node

template <typename T> class PriorityQueue
{

public: 
    template<typename T> class Node
    {
            friend typename PriorityQueue<T>;
        private:
                T data;
            int *index;
            float priority;

            public:
            Node();
            Node(T data, int *index, float priority);       
    }; 

private:
    vector<T> v;
    map<T, int*> m;
    int vSize;  
public:
    PriorityQueue();
    ~PriorityQueue();
    void insert(T obj, float priority);
    T front();
    T pop();
    bool isEmpty();
    void changePriority(T obj, float new_priority); 

};

#endif
```

PriorityQueue.cpp:

```
#include "PriorityQueue.h"
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
PriorityQueue<T>::PriorityQueue()
{
    vector<T> v;
    map<T, int*> m;
    this.vSize = 0;
}
template<class T> 
PriorityQueue<T>::~PriorityQueue()
{

}
template<class T> 
void PriorityQueue<T>::insert(T obj, float priority)
{
    Node<T> n = new Node<T>(obj, vSize, priority);

    v[vSize] = n;
    m.insert(obj, vSize);

    vSize++;
}
template<class T> 
T PriorityQueue<T>::front()
{

}
template<class T>
T PriorityQueue<T>::pop()
{  

}
template<class T>
bool PriorityQueue<T>::isEmpty()
{
    bool b = false;
    if(vSize > 0)
    {
        b = true;
        return b;
    }
    else
    {
        return b;
    }   
}   
template<class T>
void PriorityQueue<T>::changePriority(T obj, float new_priority)
{

}

template<class T>
PriorityQueue<T>::Node::Node()
{
   data = NULL;
   index = 0;
   priority = 0.0;  
}

template<class T> 
PriorityQueue<T>::Node::Node(T data, int *index, float priority)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->index = index;
    this->priority = priority;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that `Node` itself doesn't have to be a template class; it has access to the `T` of the `PriorityQueue` template because it is a nested class.  In other words, the type `PriorityQueue<int>::Node` is a different type than `PriorityQueue<float>::Node`.  (Another way to look at is that `Node` is part of the template class `PriorityQueue` and this makes it also implicitly a template.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing a semi-colon after your forward declaration of Node.  That's probably the source of the compiler headache.

Comment: Yes. In addition, as far as I can tell from the code given here, that forward-declaration itself is useless. Is the intention there to forward-declare the `Node` template that is nested inside `PriorityQueue`?